# If we evolve from microbes then why so many microbes are still here?

Tags: evolution

Researchers say that we evolve from microbes then why there are still so many microbes ?

Comment: https://blogs.iu.edu/sciu/2017/09/26/why-are-there-still-apes/

Answer (score 2):

To answer the intention of the question: evolution works by branching. To use this language of 'microbes', imagine a world with only microbe A. Say there are 100,000 individuals of the species microbe A.

Now let one of the microbe As reproduce and produce a mutation leading to the first microbe B. This evolutionary step would not transform every microbe A into a microbe B. The change would only be in the offspring of one of the 100,000 microbe A. This would create a new branch as the new microbe Bs reproduced, but would not affect the 99,999 other microbe As.

There is no reason for microbe A to die out just because a small portion of them had children that eventually became microbe B (unless they were in direct competition for limited resources, or one was a predator for the other, etc.). The other microbe As can just go on living as before, and either stay the same or branch into even more species-- say microbes C, D, E and F.

Let this run for hundreds of millions of years and you get more and more complicated life eventually resulting in what we see around us, including many species that have evolved into other species.

Note that this is very simplified for the sake of clear explanation. A mutation does not necessarily result in a new species.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the previous explanation, but said in other way:

Our evolutionary lineage may have a common ancestor (aka, a "parent species", say, another microbe [a microbe that no longer lives today, probably]) with some of today's microbes many years ago.

In this scenario, if we look at the "childs of that parent species", we may find a variety of genotypes, which will express different phenotypes.

If we look at the different childs generated in the previous step, *and iterate* that process, eventually you could get some organisms more similar to the common ancestor between us and microbes (aka, the microbes), and some individuals with a great amount of divergence from the common ancestor (aka, us).

This divergence process has to do with genetic mutations generated at reproduction of each individual.